# TextView - setting the text size programmatically doesn't seem to work

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse Indigo, testing on 2 emulators(2.2 and 3.0).

the code below shows what I am testing now, however setting the text size reveals nothing on the screen when trying to run the emulator.(if i comment out the text size the text shows up with a red color). I thought that somehow eclipse wasn't rebuilding the code but i added the line of code to add the blue background and that worked. I have tried setting the text size after setting the text with still no success. the code is below. thanks for your help! 
(disclaimer) - i am trying to stay away from xml. Being that i already know java i don't want to depend on that.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestAndroidvs2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    text.setTextSize(2);    
    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    text.setText("Hello Android");


    setContentView(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Text size 2 will be practically invisible. Try it with 14 at least. BTW, using xml has a lot of advantages and will make your life easier once you need to do anything more complex than 'Hello World'.

Comment: I will try it with 14. As i said in the first post - even if 2 is too small, that shouldn't make my screen blank should it? I guess i was reading it as a scale beyond what the text already was instead of just simply setting the size. - i will look but i will ask anyway - what is the default size? anyway thanks.

Comment: btw - yes i realize xml can have its advantages but i have zero experience with it. Yeah i know its probably easy to learn. As i already am familiar with java, i just thought it would really be useful to become familiar with as many of the classes as possible. It seems that using XML sort of hides a lot of that from you.

Comment: It doesn't hide it -- it's the same classes with the same parameters. Takes some time to be able to translate between the two, but it's actually quite efficient. As a bonus, if you define views in XML, the system takes care of different screen sizes, densities and orientations, without any need to change your code, just the layout files.

Comment: would you be able to change the layouts and orientations at run time based on any number of factors?

Comment: That's a very broad questions, but, in short, yes. Even if you define your UI in XML you can still add/remove views at run time. You can also override the default behaviour and handle orientation changes yourself.

Answer (score 633):

the method `TextView.setTextSize(int unit , float size);` takes two parameters .

Try this :

```
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
```

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_SP) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29).

**UPDATE:** 
Now the `setTextSize(float size)` will set the text size **automatically** in "**`scaled pixel`**" units. no need to mention the COMPLEX_UNIT_SP manually.
Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextSize(float)).

Comment: This is the correct answer. More specifically:

`float myTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
    18F, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`

Answer (score 92):

This fixed the issue for me.
I got uniform font size across all devices.

```
 textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font));
```

Comment: Is R.dimen.font uniform number or you have different sizes for different devices?

Comment: In my case i declared font in the files dimen.xml in these folders: values, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp with specific values.

Comment: it's weird that TextView disappeared after textView.setTextSize(R.dimen.text_size_max) called, but use your method, it works.

Answer (score 33):

Currently, `setTextSize(float size)` method will **work well** so we **don't need to use another method** for change text size

**android.widget.TextView.java** source code

```
/**
 * Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled
 * pixel" units.  This size is adjusted based on the current density and
 * user font size preference.
 *
 * <p>Note: if this TextView has the auto-size feature enabled than this function is no-op.
 *
 * @param size The scaled pixel size.
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_textSize
 */
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
}
```

Example using

```
textView.setTextSize(20); // set your text size = 20sp
```

Comment: Link to AOSP TextView source: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/37ee696d849361090a091c8fe8fad10537dabbba/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L4244-L4304

Answer (score 12):

In My Case Used this **Method**:

```
public static float pxFromDp(float dp, Context mContext) {
    return dp * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Here Set **TextView's TextSize Programatically** :

```
textView.setTextSize(pxFromDp(18, YourActivity.this));
```

Keep Enjoying:)

Comment: Hi @Dhruv Raval, I'm picking up to be able to adjust the font size in my project, in case this value 18 is valid for any screen density, or should I create a dimension for each screen?

Answer (score 11):

Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29) link for more information on setting the text size in code. Basically it says:

> public void setTextSize (int unit, float size)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Set the default text size to a given unit and
>   value. See [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) for the possible dimension units. Related XML
>   Attributes
>
> android:textSize Parameters
>
> unit  The desired dimension unit. 
>   size  The desired size in the given units.

Comment: I just double checked in Eclipse in my code and according to intellisense i actually have 2 options to setTextSize, setTextSize(float size), setTextSize(int unit, float size). The documentation that you linked confirms this.

Comment: Right - did you try it? Also Nikolay says 2 will be WAY to small to see, try increasing as well.

Comment: yes but the problem is, when i try to do it the way i have it now, the text doesnt even show up. its just a blank screen. Even if 2 wasn't noticeable why is the screen blank?

Comment: It's not blank. If you look really close, you can see the little red pixels :). Increase the size gradually to see.

Comment: And by the way, setTextSize(float) is equivalent to setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, float).

Comment: yeah as i said before i was thinking of the setText as a scale, so thats my own fault. That was kinda stupid wasn't it? :)

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, you can use simply use like this,

`textview.textSize = 20f`

Answer (score 0):

For me, nothing worked until I disabled automatic text sizing:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(TextView.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_NONE)
}
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSizeInSp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set text size using `setTextSize` method.

```
TextView.setTextsize(12);
```

Comment: setTextSize expects float not int.