# Test the size of a text on a button with getTextSize()

Tags: android, button, get, assert, text-size

I need to check if the text size on a button have the size 37sp.
I found a method to get the size with: `.getTextSize()`, but the size with I receive is: `126.0`,  and not `48sp`.
The code off button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttoneql"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="="
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="48sp" />
```

The test:

```
buttoneql = (Button) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.buttoneql);
assertEquals( 48.0f, buttoneql.getTextSize() );
```

How I should do to recive the ral value of the text size?

Comment: `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 48);` then use `scaledDensity`.Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/35843172/3395198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by multiplying the value I need (128.0) by 2.625 and rounding it up correctly to make it an integer.

```
int size = (int) Math.round (48.0 * 2.625);
```

And after, comparing to the receive value:

```
assertEquals(size, (int) buttoneql.getTextSize());
```

Comment: Put this question as write answer

Answer (score 4):

`getTextSize()` return `px` float

This is code for the convert **PX** to **SP** format.

```
view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 24);
```

Comment: How I compare this with "48sp" by using assertEquals?

Answer (score 2):

```
     float oldSize=buttoneql.getTextSize();
```

text size in float

```
    Log.d("size in float",""+oldSize);
    float dp= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

float value of scale density

```
    float newSize=oldSize/dp;
```

textsize in sp = new size

```
    Log.d("newSize in sp-->",""+newSize);
```

compare float value of text size and new size

```
    if(48.0==newSize){
        Log.d("equal size-->","true");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("equal size-->","false");
    }
```

Comment: How I compare this with "48sp" by using assertEquals?

Comment: assertEquals() methods checks that the two objects are equals or not, not there values