# How size units in Android are applied?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, view, units-of-measurement

When adding a view in an axml file, it is possible to simply specify the size and the units of the view's attribute, for example:

```
<TextView
    android:TextSize = "10sp"
    android:layout_marginTop = "10dp" />
```

But when applying a size programmatically, what are the units applied for the size sp? dp? px?

```
TextView tv = new TextView();
tv.TextSize = 10;
```

Also, how can I convert units?

Comment: this answer maybe can help u.
the question are similiar [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998938/textview-setting-the-text-size-programmatically-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: I know how to set it programmatically, yet I have no idea about the mechanism behind it.. Would be great if I could great a fully detailed answer about that subject.

Comment: @FeryAndriani Thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sp` is the default used for `TextView.TextSize`:

> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference.`

Use the `SetTextSize` method if you need a different unit type (`ComplexUnitType`):

```
textview.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Px, 20);
```

Comment: you post the same :-@

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you upvote my post if it was good so I can progress faster?

Answer (score 1):

A friend just answered me that by default Android uses "sp" for text size and "px" for view size, but it's possible to convert units like that:

```
TextView tv = new TextView();
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 10); // Sets text in px (Pixel).
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10); // Sets text in dip (Device Independent Pixels).
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10); // Sets text in sp (Scaled Pixel).
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 10); // Sets text in pt (Points).
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, 10); // Sets text in in (inches).
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 10); // Sets text in mm (millimeters).
``
```